# Webscraping using python - Keep getting repeat 1st row values from jquery table

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to scrape a list of "Name" column from this https://apps.neb-one.gc.ca/REGDOCS/Search/SearchAdvancedResults?p=4 here is my simple code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://apps.neb-one.gc.ca/REGDOCS/Search/SearchAdvancedResults? 
p=4')

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="details- 
elements"]/table/tbody/tr')

output = []

for row in rows:
    title = row.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="details- 
   elements"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/details/summary/a').get_attribute('text')
    output.append(title)

driver.close()

print(output)
```

It partly works. But for some reason the code will only return a list of 20 items (correct length), that consists of the Name (correct column) of the first row repeated (ugh...so close). Like this:

```
['Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt -
Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5', 'Receipt - Accusé de réception - A6F0I5']
```

What simple thing am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to get required output:

```
output = [item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('summary')]
```

P.S. Note that if you want to get descendants of each `row` you need to specify the dot (context) in the beginning of XPath expression:

```
for row in rows:
    row.find_element_by_xpath('.//descendant_node') # '//descendant_node' will always return you the first found node in DOM
```

Comment: List comprehension! I knew it was something simple. Worked like a charm. Thanks @Andersson.